# How to use querySelectorAll() to return ONLY certaint elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console.log all player names that are on "Power Play #1" and "Power Play #2" lists, but excluding players that are listed in the "Injuries" sections on https://www.rotowire.com/hockey/nhl-lineups.php

I tried writing a simple loop, but unfortunately, it extracts ALL players, including those listed as Injured.

I can't wrap my head around on how to exclude the injured players from console.log list as they do not have distinctive Class or ID. What can I try next?

```js
var powerplay = document.querySelectorAll('.lineup__player > a');
for (let i = 0; i < powerplay.length; i++){
console.log(powerplay[i].innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: Well the obvious first thing is maybe give injured players a distinctive class. Nobody really knows how your application works; what does "injured" mean? How does that happen? What gets updated?

Comment: Thank you replying!
I am trying to extract that data from the site for my personal analysis.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".lineup__inj").forEach(x=>x.parentElement.remove())`, then run your code. may not be the "cheapest" in "Time complexity", but it certainly works

Comment: @Yarin_007 That works. So simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list markup for which players are under an "INJURIES" section is not ideal, as the "INJURIES" header is just a direct sibling `li` of the player `li`s.

However, the type of injury is specified by an element with a class `.lineup__inj`, so you could base it off of that. You can infer that player `li`s without a `.lineup__inj` are not injured.

So what I would do is get all of the player `li`s, filter any that contain an element with the `.lineup__inj` class, then get the `a`'s `innerHTML` from each remaining element:

```js
// Need to use Array.from() to turn the NodeList into an Array so we
// can use higher order array functions.
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".lineup__player"))
  // Only keep elements that do not have `.lineup__inj` elements.
  .filter(player => !player.querySelector(".lineup__inj"))
  // Create a new array consisting of the `a` elements found within
  // each remaining li, then get the `innerHTML`.
  .map(player => player.querySelector("a").innerHTML);

console.log(players);
```

This solution is of course highly coupled to the existing markup structure, but depending on why you need this it should be fine.